# Overwrite an existing file with date as filename

Tags: powershell, overwrite

I am very new to PowerShell scripting. I am trying to overwrite an existing file with date and time in it's file name.

Here is what i'm using.

```
$LogName = "Security"
$EventID = 4725
$Date = ((get-date).addDays(-1))
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$CurrentDate = $CurrentDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh.mm.ss')
get-eventlog $LogName $EventID -after $Date | Export-CSV $Path -notypeinformation | Out-File -Filepath $Path -Append
```

However, upon running, it returns with an error that says

> Out-File : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

I hope you guys can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: `Out-File` is getting called while `Export-CSV`is still in progress. You could change this so that the export is finished before processing the last pipe but `Export-CSV` is already writing the file. There's no need for `Out-File` at all?!

Comment: It does not overwrite the file with just the Export-CSV alone because im using Get-Date with hours as part of the file name.

Comment: Not sure what you mean and you've not shown us the part where the `$Path`get's created but just to clarify what I mean: both `Export-CSV` and `Out-File` are writing to the **same** file. You can use `procmon` to verify that but as I've already said, the `Out-File` looks completely redundant to me.

Comment: @lapsantos If the answer below has helped or answered your question could you please upvote it or accepts it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ConvertTo-Csv` not `Export-CSV`.

```
Get-EventLog $LogName $EventID -after $Date | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File -Filepath $Path -Append
```

The error is down to the fact that your trying to read and write to a file ($path) at the same time.

This will stop `Export-CSV` creating a file before you append to the same file, cutting out the error.